# How can I put 3 variables from POST to AnswerId

Tags: php, mysql

My question is: How can I put 3 variables from POST to AnswerId so it will delete whole the row in my database.

This is my code:

```
$tbAlleAntId = $_POST['tbAntId1'], $_POST['tbAntId2'], $_POST['tbAntId3'];
$tbDeleteAnswerId = $tbAlleAntId;
$deleteAnt = "DELETE FROM Antwoorden WHERE AnswerId= ".$tbDeleteAnswerId;

$numRowsAnt=$dbQuiz->exec($deleteAnt);

$dbQuiz=null;
```

I am using the PDO API to connect with.

Comment: **Danger!** Your code is very vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use parameterized statements; PDO has a very nice facility for doing just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your POST variable contains safe data, create a concatenated string and  use [MySQL IN Clause](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm)

```
$tbAlleAntId = $_POST['tbAntId1'] . ',' . $_POST['tbAntId2'] . ',' . $_POST['tbAntId3'];
$deleteAnt = "DELETE FROM Antwoorden WHERE AnswerId IN(" . $tbAlleAntId . ")";
```

But you should definitely clean up your $_POST to make sure nothing harmful is sent (see [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)).

In your case one easy way could be to control that the $_POST actually contains numeric ids and nothing else.

```
if (is_numeric($_POST['tbAntId1']) && is_numeric($_POST['tbAntId2']) && is_numeric($_POST['tbAntId3'])) {
    $tbAlleAntId = $_POST['tbAntId1'] . ',' . $_POST['tbAntId2'] . ',' . $_POST['tbAntId3'];
    $deleteAnt = "DELETE FROM Antwoorden WHERE AnswerId IN(" . $tbAlleAntId . ")";
    $numRowsAnt=$dbQuiz->exec($deleteAnt);
}
```